# update document by splitted other field at mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new at mongodb.
this is my field into my collection at mongodb.

```
"BusinessCode" : "13-8-113944-15-1-0-0",
"ProcessId" : UUID("122b8301-d1d9-431c-a411-142cc169c8eb"),
"WorkItemId" : NumberLong(376935),
"WKT" : ""
```

I want split **BusinessCode** and put the first number into new field.for example I want split `13` and put it into other field called `Domain`.

```
"Domain" : "13"
```

according this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/), seems I have to use `update` but I don't know who to write `<query>` for my scenario.
thanks for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Comment: Currently not supported.. multiple jira tickets opened for improvement https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11345

Comment: @sidgate no it is not the same.I want to `split string of  field's value` and then do updating my document.

Comment: you want to create new field from existing field, which is similar to the linked question. This feature is not supported as of now. The linked question has alternative, for instance, iterate and update one document at a time.. you can do splitting in your code for each document

Comment: my main question is splitting .I want just first string before line(-). in my scenario 13.I write this `{ $project : {BusinessCode : {$split: [ "$BusinessCode" ,"- "]}}},` but it doesn't right.

Comment: do you want to update the existing document with new `domain` field, or just want to project it?

Comment: @sidgate I want to update the existing document with new domain field.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I would answer this, odd it is not answered already:

```js
db.collection.update( 
  { },  
  [ { $set : { Domain: { 
                  $arrayElemAt: [ { 
                            $split: [ "$BusinessCode" , "-" ] }, 0 ] 
                       } } } ] , 
  { multi: true } )
```